# How to determine program success when running a sequence of similar tasks?

Tags: bash, command-line, arguments, exit-status, conventions

I am writing a series of CLI tools that share the same parent command, similar to programs like `git`.

```
program verb OPTIONS
```

One of the action verbs, `install`, is designed to `git clone` as many repositories as URLs are specified.

What is a robust and UNIX-like logical way to determine program success or failure?

1. Good URLs > 0 → EXIT_SUCCESS
2. Bad URLs == 0 → EXIT_SUCCESS
3. Write number of valid URLs to standard output, then (1) or (2)
4. Return the number of valid URLs.
5. **Other?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program should at least [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) `EXIT_SUCCESS` (i.e. 0) on success and probably `EXIT_FAILURE` (i.e. 1) on failure. You could copy (or be inspired by) [FreeBSD sysexits.h](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%204.3-RELEASE&format=html) for more failure codes (but I am not sure it is worth the effort).

Don't forget to give some message to *stderr* (or thru [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html)) for any kind of failure. From what you describes, failing to `git clone` even one (amongst many) repository for your `install` subcommand should be a failure.

The user would probably do some corrective action (e.g. correct the spelling of the faulty URL) and then repeat the same command, so you might want it to be idempotent.

Don't forget a `--help` option, and document any exit code outside of 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks. Very simple approach. I see yo do not recommend returning the number of successful downloads, but rather set the exit status depending on whether the command succeeded or not. What would be a robust way to communicate the number of successful downloads then?

Comment: Output to *stdout*, *stderr* or some command specified file (or file descriptor)

Comment: Thank you for the useful links and overall great advice, nevermind the bash tag. Accepted.